# Interfacing to a scrollbar in NSScrollView

Tags: swift, macos, nsscrollview

I have a custom `NSView`.  Its contents may be wider than the screen.
I've used the Interface Builder to embed my custom view into an `NSScrollView`.  The scroll view contains a horizontal `NSScroller` and an `NSClipView` containing my custom view.

I override `NSView.draw(_:)` as follows:

```
var frameSet = false
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
    print("bounds \(bounds)") // Always shows origin of 0.0, 0.0
    if !frameSet {
        frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width*2, height: bounds.height)
        frameSet = true
    }
    let scrollView = enclosingScrollView
    let scroller = scrollView!.horizontalScroller
    scroller!.isEnabled = true  // This is necessary
    let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext
    // draw stuff
}
```

The scroll bar appears on the screen, and I can drag it back and forth, but it has no effect on my custom view.  What I would expect is the following:

1. I would expect `NSView.bounds` to somehow reflect the state of the horizontal scrollbar.  But the bounds rect always has an origin of 0,0 regardless of the state of the scrollbar.
2. I would expect that when the scrollbar is moved, it would set `NSView.needsDisplay` to force a redraw.  This is not happening.

What I can do is to query the state of the scrollbar in my `draw(_:)` method.

```
var frameSet = false
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
    print("bounds \(bounds)") // Shows previous setting
    if !frameSet {
        frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width*2, height: bounds.height)
        frameSet = true
    }
    let scrollView = enclosingScrollView
    let scroller = scrollView!.horizontalScroller
    scroller!.isEnabled = true  // This is necessary
    let knobRect = scroller!.rect(for: NSScroller.Part.knob)
    bounds = NSRect(x: knobRect.minX, y: bounds.minY, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
    print( "new bounds \(bounds)")   // This works
    let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext
    // draw stuff
}
```

I could live with this if there were some way to force the redraw.  But I suspect that this should all be handled automatically.

What am I missing?

Comment: `draw(_:)` should draw, nothing else. 1. `bounds` doesn't change, try `visibleRect`. 2. The scroll view caches portions of the view. What is the initial frame size of the view in the xib/storyboard? Do you change the frame size somewhere else? Did you add or change any constraints inside the scroll view?

Comment: The frame size is variable depending on the data.  I moved the code to set the frame size out of draw(_:), and I call it whenever the data is updated.  However it doesn't have any effect.  If I assign a new value to frame, it doesn't stick.  Frame always has an origin of zero, and a size matching the visible area on the sceen.  dirtyRect, bounds, visibleRect all show the origin I set on the previous iteration of draw, and a size matching the visible area on the sceen.

Comment: The constraints in the Interface Builder seem to be OK.  The drawing area expands and contracts properly when the overall window gets resized.